# Remove broken cartridge of a Moen shower faucet

Tags: faucet, cartridge

I already watched some YouTube videos regarding how to remove a Moen cartridge, but  my issue is a little different.

As shown in the pictures, the cartridge itself was broken. Since it's not fully turned off before it's broken, water continues to flow - I had to turn off the main water valve of the house to stop it.

[image] 
[image]
[image]
A few questions here, that I wonder if you can kindly help out:

- I couldn't tell what model this Moen cartridge is, 1222, 1225 or something else?
- Given that it's broken, will the regular cartridge remover be able to take out the cartridge? Like [this one from Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00083EC6C)?
- Is it still possible to turn off the faucet? I guess it's hard, but I really don't want to keep the main water valve shut off all the time, and obviously it'll take days to find a solution & get a replacement.
- What kind of cartridge can be used as a replacement? Again, this is related to first question. I know I need to look up the manual but couldn't find it in my house, sorry.

Comment: Have a look at the Q&A section for the Amazon product you listed. Someone asked there if the puller will work if the stem is broken out likes yours is. The manufacturer said no, but several others provided ideas on how they got cartridges out that were broken just like yours is. You may find a useful answer there.

Comment: thanks to @dwizum, those Q&A did help, I found this video really helped: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xErpfoeY-TA . Now I got the cartridge pulled out.

Answer (score 2):

You should still be able to get the cartridge out.  In your bottom left picture, there's a little copper-colored tab sticking out (between 12 and 1 O'Clock, to the left of the threaded hole.)  You pull that out straight up and then the cartridge pulls out toward you.  I would think a pair of pliers would work for that.  Then what I do is take it to the hardware store and compare side-to-side and find the match.

Comment: thank you! I followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xErpfoeY-TA and got the cartridge pulled out.